# Odoo 11 : How to get current record in javascript

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

this is my python function

```
class SaleOrder(models.Model):
_inherit = 'sale.order'
@api.model
def get_order(self):
order=request.env['sale.order'].sudo().search([('id','=',self.id)])
    print(order.name)
    return(order)
```

this is my javascript code :

```
var rpc = require('web.rpc');
        rpc.query({
            model:'sale.order',
            method:'get_order',
        }).then(function (result) { 
            console.log("Done");

});
```

The result in the log is  empty

So "self" is empty, but why ?

And how my function can do work ?

Anybody can help me please

Comment: I don't know Odoo, but where's the ID supposed to come from? From the session object, or from the last page requested, or something else? Do you need to pass it back to the server from the javascript code?

Comment: usually when you write order=request.env['sale.order'].sudo().search([('id','=',self.id)]) 
order will containt the current sale order 
in odoo self means this

Comment: Sure: I meant where did the self object get the ID from?

Comment: get it from database

Comment: the problem is when calling py from js self contains the object of this model without any records

Comment: Please provide the complete context of your case. Like for example: from where are you executing your js code?. And any other helpful detail to be able to provide you with the changes your code needs

Comment: _onInputFocusout: function () {
     var self = this;
        if(this.name == "route_id"){
         var rpc = require('web.rpc');
         rpc.query({
          model:'sale.order',
          method:'get_order',
         }).then(function (result) { 
                console.log("Done");

    });
         
       }
  
    },

Answer (score 3):

The function need to be instance level then only self will contain a record reference.

In your example, the function is **@api.model** type it needs to be in **@api.multi** hen you will get record in self. In case of **@api.model** self is representing model.

If you are using is JS code in form view widget then you already have current record just try **this.field_manager.datarecord** and you will get current record.

Comment: This helped me. Thanks.